# How to type a Backus-Naur form in LaTeX

Tags: packages, formatting

I need to type Backus-Naur form in LaTeX document. I found several packages on CTAN:

- [ebnf](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=ebnf) seems to not work with TeXLive 2009
- [latex-bnf](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=latex-bnf) does not align the declaration, etc.
- There is a module for ConTeXt, [context-bnf](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/context/contrib/context-bnf/doc/context/third/bnf/)

Is there a package for modern LaTeX, or should I just use hand-formatting via verbatim?

Comment: Not `verbatim`, for goodness sake. If everything else fails, use an `itemize` or something like that. I hope someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Please note that I mentioned `verbatim` as last resort. Probably `tabular` would be closer to what I have in mind but neither of those solution is IMHO LaTeX-like (i.e. type the document and let computer to figure out how to format it).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars

Comment: I have found the `syntax` package very easy to use, thanks to [this detailed answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24934/10140).

Comment: The simplebnf package (https://github.com/Zeta611/simplebnf) is straightforward to use. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I stumbled across the [`syntax-mdw` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw) the other day. It looks like it might typeset BNFs and syntax diagrams nicely.  See the [documentation (PDF)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/syntax.pdf) to get an idea of its capabilities.

Comment: If the package's underscore hack causes problems then try `\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}`.

Comment: I needed to use `[nounderscore]` otherwise I got the error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Answer (score 3):

Try the `bnf.tex` at http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/bnf/ . It is simple enough that can form the basis of what you are looking and expand as you wish.