# Create and center nice EBNF

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I used the package `syntax` to create the following EBNF.

1. I would like to center it, however `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and other commands do not seem to work on the `grammar` environment.
2. When I set `\grammarindent` to a larger value also the `::=` gets indented. Do you have an idea how I can indent the `\alt` behind the `::=`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
\begin{document}
\shortverb{\|}
\setlength{\grammarindent }{2cm}
\begin{grammar}
<stmt> ::= <stmt>; <stmt> | \textbf{skip} | $v := $ <expr> | \textbf{input} $\vec{v}$ | \textbf{output} $\vec{v}$
        \alt \textbf{if} <expr> \textbf{then} <stmt> \textbf{else} <stmt> | \textbf{while} <expr> <stmt>

<expr> ::= $v$ | \textbf{tt} | \textbf{ff} | <expr> $\lor$ <expr> | $\lnot$<expr>.
\end{grammar} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Which package can be used to write BNF grammars?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grammar` environment is based on a `list` structure, which is naturally left aligned.  One way to get a centering effect is to put the whole structure into a `minipage` inside a `center` environment.

The original command `\alt` is defined to be

```
 \\\llap{\textbar\quad}
```

i.e. this starts an new line and prints to the left of the new column a vertical bar followed by a space of one `\quad` = `1em`.  You can just define a similar command that removes the `\llap` so the vertical bar (and space) are not pushed out leftwards.  However, I suggest a command that does a little more:

```
\newcommand{\indalt}[1][2]{\\\hspace*{#1em}\textbar\quad}
```

This provides by default `2em` of extra space before the bar, but takes an optional argument so `\indalt[0]` will give no indent and `\indent[4]` will give an indent of `4em`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}

\shortverb{\|}
\setlength{\grammarindent}{2cm}
\newcommand{\indalt}[1][2]{\\\hspace*{#1em}\textbar\quad}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
    \begin{grammar}
      <stmt> ::= <stmt>; <stmt> | \textbf{skip} | $v := $ <expr>
      \indalt \textbf{input} $\vec{v}$ | \textbf{output} $\vec{v}$
      \indalt[4] \textbf{if} <expr> \textbf{then} <stmt> \textbf{else} <stmt>
      \indalt \textbf{while} <expr> <stmt>

      <expr> ::= $v$ | \textbf{tt} | \textbf{ff} | <expr> $\lor$
      <expr> | $\lnot$<expr>.
    \end{grammar}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you wish to redfine the `\alt` command itself you will have to do this in the `grammar` environment itself, as it is not defined globally.