# syntax package prevents underscores in file names

Tags: input, grammar

I'm working in Overleaf, and using the syntax package for Backus-Naur notation, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars). However, it seems to interfere with using the `\input` command on files with underscores in their names. Here is a minimal working example, where `my_file.tex` is in the same directory as `main.tex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{syntax}


\begin{document}

\input{my_file}
\end{document}
```

This gives `Latex Error: file my@uscore.file not found`. The error goes away if I either comment out `\usepackge{syntax}` or remove the underscore in the file name. I'd rather not have to remove all underscores from file names, because I have a whole naming convention that I always use, across multiple projects. Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: the `syntax` package changes `_` to make it active. Additionally, `syntax` has not been updated since 1996 so might not work well with modern latex.

Comment: You could use `\input{my\string_file}` but the package should not be doing that

Comment: `\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}`, if you really want to use the package.

Comment: Thanks, all three of these work: [nounderscore], \string and \detokenize. I guess \detokenize might be the best? but they all do the job in my case

Comment: That other post does answer my question yes. I had a skim before posting here but thought it was different because of the mention of graphicx.