# Treat grammar as listing

Tags: listings, grammar

I have a `grammar` in my document using the package `syntax` like described in the answer to [How to type a Backus-Naur form in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/how-to-type-a-backus-naur-form-in-latex).

Now I want it to be treated like the listings I have in my document. This means I want to add a label, a caption (that says "Listing 42" in the beginning) and it should appear in `\lstlistoflistings`. Is there a way to achive this?

A strongly simplified example of my document so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tablecaptionabove]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
\begin{document}
   \lstlistoflistings

    some Text

    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing},label=myListing]
        myListingCode
    \end{lstlisting}

    some Text

    \begin{grammar}
        <S> ::= someTerminal
    \end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a new environment that calls the caption type to be the same as for a `lstlisting`, with the help of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tablecaptionabove]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to provide mock text

\newenvironment{BNF}
  {\captionsetup{type=lstlisting}}
  {}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing},label=myListing]
myListingCode
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{BNF}
\caption{A grammar}
\begin{grammar}
   <S> ::= someTerminal
\end{grammar}
\end{BNF}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]