# How do I include the EBNF square brackets on a new line and set the font to typewriter throughout my grammar in the syntax package?

Tags: formatting, packages, syntax, grammar

I want to add an EBNF grammar to my document and following the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/how-to-type-a-backus-naur-form-in-latex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars), it seems that the most popular package for this is [`syntax`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdwtools/syntax.pdf).

However, in the documentation it is not clear how to support constructs such as optional items enclosed in square brackets on multiple lines. I tried to use both `[` and `\[` directly but both do not work inside the `\begin{grammar}` block. Inserting `[` after a `\\` outputs an error, while `\[` puts the line centered and adds a lot of vertical space before and after it.

Is there a proper way to include optional items in EBNF using `syntax`?

I would also like to change the font to use typewriter font throughout, and not have this continuous changing of typewriter and normal font. Not sure what is the right way to achieve this. The [syntax documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdwtools/syntax.pdf) is a bit confusing in this regard.

I've included a minimal example below where I have the first rule including the `[` which works, but it is on the same line, the second rule including a line break, which works, but does not start with `[`, while the third one which includes both, and reports a strange error `Missing number, treated as zero`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}

<a> ::= "a" [<b>]

<b> ::= "b" \\ <c>

%this does not work
<c> ::= "c" \\ [<d>]

\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

I would like to know what is the right way to put the optional parameter on the new line with the `[` and how to change the font of BNF grammars to typewriter font throughout. (Not the rest of the document of course).

Comment: Please provide a minimal example document demonstrating the issue. That will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Have you see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars)?

Comment: @cfr Yes I did, it is linked from the one I referred to in my question. There is no mention of square brackets there either (or of setting the font).

Comment: Maybe the stuff below helps? I think the documentation assumes you know how NFSS works. If you do, it tells you enough. If you don't, it provides no clue as to what to look up to figure it out. (NFSS = New Font Selection Scheme which is basically how LaTeX-2e thinks about all things font.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exploit `\new@ifnextchar` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\grammar}{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\syntleft}{$\langle$\normalfont\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}

<a> ::= "a" [<b>]

<b> ::= "b" \\ <c>

<c> ::= "c" \\ [<d>]

\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

With this trick, `\\` will consider a following `[` to introduce the optional argument only if no space intervenes.

I've used cfr's code for changing the font. The packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are recommended for Times with math fonts support. If you don't like the typewriter font they provide, it's easy to change it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. For some reason my system cannot find the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. (It is set to download packages automatically of course, and I did a Synchronize on the MikTeX Package Manager just in case.) Do I need to change repository to a more updated one or something? Also what is the `xpatch` package being used for? (I left it out and the solution seems to work just the same)

Comment: @jbx Those packages are just a suggestion for how to replace `\usepackage{times}`. Possibly your document loads `etoolbox`, perhaps via `biblatex`, so `\pretocmd` is already defined without needing `xpatch`.

Comment: Yes I already use `biblatex` and `etoolbox` in fact. What could be the reason why those 2 fonts are not working? I tried to change my repository to another CTAN mirror, with version 14-Jan-16 but still the same problem. (The PDF doesn't even generate when I put those packages)

Comment: @jbx I'm no expert with MiKTeX. Try looking for `newtx` in the package listing. In general, I suggest to do a full install of a TeX system: it's much easier to manage.

Comment: Yes in package manager I can see `newtx` also saying 'Installed on 2016-01-19' so I presume it's today after I included it in my tex file. I suspect it might be related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287033/newtx-wont-load . Maybe I should try updating my MikTeX installation, it is over 2 years old I think.

Comment: I updated MikTeX and now they work fine. For the benefit of other Windows / MikTeX users. I ran `miktex-update_admin.exe` and it showed various packages that needed to be updated, but couldn't before the miktex binaries were first updated. So it could be a reason why `newtx` didn't work before. Is there a nice typewriter font that goes with `newtx`?

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your question is not specific to the **syntax** package. The problem is that in environments such as `array` and `tabular` and `grammar`, `\\` directly followed by an opening square bracket is assumed to introduce an adjustment to vertical spacing. And a space beforehand doesn't prevent the next relevant token counting as the `[`. You don't want an adjustment, but that's just like an adjustment of zero, I think, so you can say `\\[0pt] [<d>]` and everything should work OK. Alternatively, you could define a special command to create the square brackets or write `\\{}` in place of `\\[0pt]` if that's better.

Note that **times** is long deprecated and ought not be used. I've used **tgtermes** here, but there are other options if you don't like this particular choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}

  <a> ::= "a" [<b>]

  <b> ::= "b" \\ <c>

  % this works
  <c> ::= "c" \\[0pt] [<d>]
  % or this
%  <c> ::= "c" \\{} [<d>]

\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

[image: square brackets]

The documentation does say something about changing the fonts (page 10) but it rather assumes that you know how to do this in the general case.

The commands it lists as affecting the appearance of different typeset elements are

```
\syntleft
\syntright
\ulitleft
\ulitright
\litleft
\litright
```

So, to change these, we need the origiinal definitions. The manual provides this for the first two:

```
\newcommand{\syntleft}{$\langle$\normalfont\itshape}
\newcommand{\syntright}{$\rangle$}
```

The `\normalfont` is setting the font to the default family for the document (usually serif). The `\itshape` sets the italic. If we want to use the typewriter family instead of serif, we can say

```
\renewcommand{\syntleft}{$\langle$\normalfont\ttfamily\itshape}
```

If we wanted the upright shape, we could say

```
\renewcommand{\syntleft}{$\langle$\normalfont\ttfamily}
```

We don't need to change the right one because it doesn't affect the font. The default definitions for the remaining 4 commands are as follows:

```
\newcommand{\ulitleft}{\normalfont\ttfamily\syn@ttspace\frenchspacing}
```

This changes the font but it already changes it to typewriter, so nothing to worry about here.

```
\newcommand{\ulitright}{}
\newcommand{\litleft}{`\bgroup\ulitleft}
\newcommand{\litright}{\ulitright\egroup'}
```

These don't affect the font, so nothing to do here either.

So, the one change of command yields this result in place of the original above:

[image: all typewriter]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{syntax}
\renewcommand{\syntleft}{$\langle$\normalfont\ttfamily\itshape}
% \newcommand{\syntright}{$\rangle$}
% \newcommand{\ulitleft}{\normalfont\ttfamily\syn@ttspace\frenchspacing}
% \newcommand{\ulitright}{}
% \newcommand{\litleft}{`\bgroup\ulitleft}
% \newcommand{\litright}{\ulitright\egroup'}
\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}

  <a> ::= "a" [<b>]

  <b> ::= "b" \\ <c>

  % this works
  <c> ::= "c" \\[0pt] [<d>]
  % or this
%  <c> ::= "c" \\{} [<d>]

\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `tgtermes`. Any ideas how to make the grammar part in typewriter font instead of times / tgtermes? (the times part is for the normal document text).

Comment: @jbx Please see edit. I posted it 1 min before you posted you comment.... ;)

Comment: Thanks trying it out. Is there a way to avoid that `[0pt]` on each line? I have a grammar which has lots of new lines in it and it is going to become quite polluted. I guess I will have to stick with it if there is no other way.

Comment: @jbx The other thing you could do would be to define a command to produce the square bracket. Or you can say `\\{}` if that's better than `\\[0pt]`. You have to somehow change the token stream so that TeX does not see `\\[` and expect a number next. I don't think it would be a good idea to try to alter the way TeX reads the stream because that may be important 'behind the scenes' here even if you don't explicitly rely on it in your code.

Comment: ok thanks. I will work with it like that for now. On another note, I am using package `courier` too for listings and these kinds of things. Is that also outdated? Where can I get some info on the latest up to date fonts to use?

Comment: I don't think that is deprecated in the way Times is. However, if you like Termes, you might want to use **tgcursor** which provides a typewriter family and maybe **tgheros** which provides sans. This provides clones of the 3 fonts people tend to group together when they select Times. [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is a good source of information and kept fairly up-to-date, as well as links to further information.

Comment: OK thanks for the information. I will try `tgcursor` out. Accepted your answer. Need to wait 22hrs to award the bounty, will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. No rush to award the bounty. Wait and see if anybody suggests a more convenient solution. At least wait until Alan Munn has had a chance to have a look.