# Comfortably typesetting Extended Backus-Naur-Form

Tags: formatting, packages, grammar

On this site I've found some solutions how to typeset Backus-Naur-Forms, e.g.:

- [How to type a Backus-Naur form in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4455/124577)
- [Which package can be used to write BNF grammars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24886/124577)

Unfortunately both solution are very uncomfortable for use with Extended Backus-Naur-Form. That especially includes `[ optional ]` and `{ some more }` constructions which were added.

I wonder if there is a package that enables me to typeset EBNF with the following requirements:

- logic markup (nonterminal and terminal symbols, terminal descriptions),
- automated line-break (and something like hanging with indentation instead of `|` f.i. [because `|` is used for or])
- numbered and unnumbered production rules
- (optional) hyperref support for jumping to nonterminal definitions

*Question:* Is there a package that is able to do that? If not, how should I start implementing (list, paragraphs, ...)?

A dummy document (what I think it could look like):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{ebnf}
\prodrule{nonterm} \nonterm{thing} [ \term{option} ] \{ \termdesc{something} \} | \nonterm{variable}
\prodrule{thing} \term{object}
\prodrule{variable} \termdesc{anything}
\end{ebnf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to try and begin coding in Plain TeX.

Comment: @daunaf Feel free to. For me, plain TeX sounds like the wrong tool. I was looking for an idiomatic LaTeX interface which is best defined in terms of LaTeX. And I'm sure that these days expl3 is the easier way to do the background programming. But if you have a plain TeX solution, then please share it :)

Comment: I don't know anything about ebnf but there's a package [naive-ebnf](https://ctan.org/pkg/naive-ebnf) that at least supports the `[optional]` and `{repetition}` constructions. Doesn't seem to support numbered/unnumbered prod. rules or hyperref. Not sure about the line breaking

Comment: See also this topic on ctan: https://ctan.org/topic/formal-spec

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you but I don't seem to see any package ticking all boxes. Is there anything I am missing? (After so many years most of this is academic interest but if I'd need something like this again I'd basically still need all the features described here.)

Comment: @TeXnician, hm, don't know. Besides programming your own package(s) I'd suggest taking a different route of finding. // E.g. `ebnf editor` can be a search term: perhaps some nice program does what you need, and you can somehow use its output. // E.g. entering a few scripts (= search story) into https://phind.com might give you clues. I suggest less reading and trusting in its written output and more see it as a different search engine, as it puts its sources, too. // Also try said search term at https://patents.google.com , less for solutions, more for contacts.

Comment: @MS-SPO You may surely be right that there are non-TeXy routes. And while I had my workarounds back then, this is the TeX site, so this question explicitly asks for the TeX solution ;)

Comment: @TeXnician, sigh, to find a TeX-solution sometimes you need to break this requirement on purpose, just to discover a route toward TeX, which then is obvious, but hidden today. Terminus technicus is "breaking psychological inertia", which is intended to describe, not to judge ;-) We all have it, and the sooner we break it, the better and faster we arrive at solutions.